# Why doesn't the summary tab have boxes for favorites, responses, and activity?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, tabs, summary

There are short summaries of each tab in the Summary tab of your profile, which are very helpful for moving here and there. However, I don't understand why there is no short summary of some other tabs.

I think a short summary of the favorites tab would be useful for moving in between favorites easily via the summary page.

Why doesn't the summary tab have boxes for the favorites, responses, and activity tabs?

My responses and activity tabs are not shown to other users, but that tab's short summary can be shown to only me, couldn't it? Can anyone provide reasons as to why these tabs are not includes in the summary?

Comment: Your second question there at the end doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The questions are actually the same thing.

Comment: Yup I have edited it. I want reason for each tab. But was not able to frame question correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The summary to the **responses** tab is essentially the global inbox. You already receive instant notifications of comments directed at you, and answers posted to your questions. There's really no point in duplicating that summary in your personal profile.

I suppose we could do this for the **favorites** tab, but I think that the entire favorites system is in need of an overhaul, so I wouldn't waste too much time on adding a stop-gap summary for it to the profile. Additionally, other people who visit your profile are unlikely to care about the recent status of your favorites. If and when *you* care, you can simply visit the appropriate tab.

The **activity** tab contains *way* too much information for me to imagine how we could succinctly "summarize" it. It literally displays all of your activity on that particular site in chronological order, and provides options to filter it by the type of activity. What would a summary of that look like? What would it omit? And why would anyone want to see a quick overview of that? Whenever I look at the "activity" tab, I'm investigating something—either long-term trends, suspicious behavior, or something like that. I want to have all of the information at my disposal.

Comment: +1 - This is pretty much what I had to say, and in more words.

Comment: +1. Satisfied with reason for responses and activity tab. And partially for favourites tab. I know other people don't care much about my favourites. But I do care a lot. I visit 2-4 times whenever I visits favourites. That's why feeling favourites summary. ( Other people may not feel it's necessity.)